# Picking larger numbers in succession between two list of integers

Tags: python, list, algorithm, sorting

I have been trying to make a Python code that is straightforward in concept but I have been unsuccessful at figuring out how to do so with an elegant code.

Basically, given two ascending-sorted lists of integers:

```
A = [5, 6, 7, 9, 35, 47, 88, 100] 
B = [3, 12, 44, 78, 94, 122, 186] 
C = []
```

Starting from list A, I want to bin the next higher number in a successive list (A-B-A-B-A. As such) into an empty list C.

In execution, this would produce

```
C = [5,12,35,44,47,78,88,94,100,122]
```

And end at 122, as we cannot find any number higher in list A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) to flip between the two lists. Once you can do this, you can use `filter()` to get the next larger value from the current iterator and keep track of the largest seen so far.

```
from itertools import  cycle

def get_seq(A, B):
    if not A:  # handle case where A is empty
        return
        
    its = cycle((iter(A), iter(B)))
    current_val = A[0] - 1

    for i in its:
        try:
            current_val = next(filter(lambda n: n > current_val, i))
        except StopIteration:
            return
        yield current_val
    
            
A = [5, 9, 35, 47, 88, 100] 
B = [3, 12, 44, 78, 94, 122, 186] 

list(get_seq(A, B))
# [5, 12, 35, 44, 47, 78, 88, 94, 100, 122]
```

If you *know* `A` won't be empty you can simplify this a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Define a function get_index to get the index of the next larger element, and then append the elements in turn, where the sig is used to distinguish the order between the A and B lists：

```
def get_index(lst, value):
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        if lst[i] > value:
            return i


def solution(a, b):
    res, sig, index_a, index_b = [], True, 0, 0
    while True:
        if sig:
            if len(res):
                index_a = get_index(a, res[-1])
            item = a[index_a]
            res.append(item)
            if item >= b[-1]:
                break
            sig = False
        else:
            index_b = get_index(b, res[-1])
            item = b[index_b]
            res.append(item)
            if item >= a[-1]:
                break
            sig = True

    return res

A = [5, 6, 7, 9, 35, 47, 88, 100]
B = [3, 12, 44, 78, 94, 122, 186]

print(solution(A, B))
# [5,12,35,44,47,78,88,94,100,122]
```

Comment: Thank you, appreciated this code being free of using certain modules

Answer (score 0):

We can join the lists and trigger between them.

If you expect some huge list with only few elements being used, binary search approach (commented) might be better than linear scan.

```
#import bisect

A = [5, 6, 7, 9, 35, 47, 88, 100]
B = [3, 12, 44, 78, 94, 122, 186]
AB = [A,B]
lens = [len(A), len(B)]
C = []
curr = [0, 0]
idx = 0
while curr[idx] < lens[idx]:
    val = AB[idx][curr[idx]]
    C.append(val)
    idx = 1 - idx

    #curr[idx] = bisect.bisect_right(AB[idx], val + 1, curr[idx] + 1)

    while curr[idx] < lens[idx] and AB[idx][curr[idx]] <= val:
        curr[idx] += 1

print(C)
```